# How to prove that hom set in semiadditive category has monoidal structure?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $f,g\in \text{Hom}(a,b)$. I want to define $f+g\in\text{Hom}(a,b)$ and show that $f+g=g+f$.

I took $\varphi\in \text{Hom}(a, b\oplus b)$ such that $f=\pi_1\circ \varphi$ and $g=\pi_2\circ\varphi$, and took $\nabla_b\in\text{Hom}(b\oplus b,b)$ such that $\nabla_b\circ i_1=\nabla_b\circ i_2=\text{id}_b$. I wrote $f+g=\nabla_b\circ \varphi$.

Then, to show the commutativity, I let $f=\pi_2\circ \varphi'$ and $g=\pi_1\circ \varphi'$, and tried to show $\nabla_b\circ \varphi=\nabla_b\circ \varphi'$. I guess I need to construct an $\text{id}_{b\oplus b}$ and write $\nabla_b\circ\varphi=\nabla_b\circ \text{id}_{b\oplus b}\circ \varphi$, but I have no idea how to do it. What condition am I missing? Or is $\nabla_b\circ \varphi=\nabla_b\circ\varphi'$ true?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan could you please show me some details? I see why they are isomorphic, but I don't see how I can use it to show the commutativity.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I spoke too soon. You can check out a blog post I wrote where I prove commutativity in a different way by defining the commutative monoid structure more indirectly: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Composing the codiagonal in all possible ways with itself gives maps $M \sqcup ... \sqcup M \to M$ which are all uniquely determined by the requirement that all of the corresponding maps $M \to M$ are$\text{id}_M$, so $\nabla$ is commutative and associative.

I don't get this either. Why do the morphisms $M\to M \sqcup ... \sqcup M$ not matter?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I kind of get it now... Thank you for your help and your blog!